# biblatex: strictly identical footnote citations following each other

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using the `verbose-trad2` citation style of **biblatex** and trying to change some things around. In my style, *Idem* is more restricted than just identical author name, so I set `idemtracker=false`. I also redefined the appropriate bibliography string (ibidem), so that I get, for example,

1. Author name, « Title », *op cit*., p. X
2. *Idem*, p. Y.

if two citations following each other share the same author and title, but differ in the page number in the postnote. That's all well.

Now, if the page is the same in the two citations, I'd like the page reference to be suppressed in the second citation (that's taken care of with `ibidpage=true`). Moreover, in this case only, I'd like the Latin abbreviation to be *Ibid.* instead of *Idem*. Is there a way to do this?

Here are links to some files:

- [my biblatex code](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/codeBiblatex201206.tex)
- [example .tex](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.tex)
- [example .bbl](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.bbl)
- and the resulting [pdf](http://www.silentdrift.net/biblatex/example201206.pdf)

Thanks for your time and any help!

Comment: What you are looking for is usually handled by the `loccittracker` I think (you would need to rename the string, though). Sorry I don't have time to look into it now – I see you enabled it, there must be something preventing it from being really switched on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `ibidpage=true` you also get `loccittracker=constrict`. The case where you want *Ibid* instead of *Idem* is detected by the `\ifloccit` test. Under `verbose-trad2`, this test is executed in the `cite:ibid` bibliography macro. Here is its definition from `verbose-trad2.cbx`:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}
```

You can redefine this macro to print *Idem* when `\ifloccit` yields `false`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,ibidpage,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{knuth:ct:a}.
Filler text \autocite{knuth:ct:b}.
Same labelname, different work \autocite{knuth:ct:a}.
Same work, different postnote \autocite[16]{knuth:ct:a}.
Same work, same postnote \autocite[16]{knuth:ct:a}.
Same labelname, different work \autocite[10]{knuth:ct:b}.
Same work, same postnote \autocite[10]{knuth:ct:b}.
Same work, different postnote \autocite[10--15]{knuth:ct:b}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bingo, works perfectly well! I just needed to remove the bibliography string definition I mentioned in my question. Thank you very much Audrey!